# How to run a batch file from a network share in Vista without the warning dialog?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

> The publisher could not be verified. Are you sure you want to run this software?

How can I automatically run this bat file on startup without the popup blocking it?  The batch file is on a network share on another computer.

Comment: This should probably be on Superuser.

Answer (score 4):

**ETA:** You mentioned in your comment that this appears when running the batch from another machine in the network. In this case the zone from which the file comes from is pretty much self-evident and doesn't need to be in the stream. You can remove that warning by following the following steps:

1. Open Internet Explorer's<sup>1</sup> *Internet Options*
2. Click the Security tab
3. Select the "Local Intranet" zone
4. Click the "Sites" Button
5. Click the "Advanced" Button
6. Add the network name of the computer you're running the batch from as follows:

   ```
   file://computername
   ```

This will cause the specified computer to count into the "Local intranet" zone which won't trigger the warning as you have chosen to trust it.

(Thanks to the [*How-To Geek*](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-the-annoying-this-page-has-an-unspecified-potential-security-risk-when-using-files-on-a-network-share/) on this one.)

---

For local batch files, the solution is not hard:

Batch files don't have digital signatures and, to my knowledge, can't have them. What you're seeing is likely the result of downloading the batch file from a website. This causes an Alternate Data Stream named `Zone.Identifier` to be created. You can remove this by choosing "Unblock" in the properties of the file

[image: Illustration of the "Unblock" button in the properties dialog]

or by redirecting nothing<sup>2</sup> into the stream:

```
echo.>foo.cmd:Zone.Identifier
```

---

<sup>1</sup> They partially are for the whole system and partially IE-specific.

<sup>2</sup> Or at least nothing Explorer will recognize as valid content of that stream.

Comment: Thanks for this - other sites didn't mention the file:// prefix, without which it doesn't work (at least for me in Win7)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on it and choose Unblock.

Comment: Yes, I run the bat file from another PC. Where do you find the unblock icon. Not on my bat properties ??